# How to redirect to home page when user click on Enter or Cancel button in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, css

i want to make functionality in wordpress just like this here is the [Example](http://iiap.ae/)! 
when domain url is loaded first time,registration form will appear and if user click on enter or cancel than it will be redirected to home page after this form would not be appear again in site any where, guide me what files i have to make and where will be the proper placement of those files just like reg-form.php?

Comment: add a new page Regstration assign reg-template and set as static page in readings, than session will created after submit of form than check condition if is_set($_SESSION[]){ //want to redirect here } but there is one issue if i set Registration as static it works just like index...

Answer (score 0):

use the plugin below to setup popup and it provide html content to add your content/form

http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-popup/